# applying business rules at the database level

Tags: sql, database, oracle, rule-engine, business-rules

I'm working on a project in which we will need to determine certain types of statuses for a large body of people, stored in a database.  The business rules for determining these statuses are fairly complex and may change.

For example,

```
if a person is part of group X 
and (if they have attribute O) has either attribute P or attribute Q, 
or (if they don't have attribute O) has attribute P but not Q,
and don't have attribute R, 
and aren't part of group Y (unless they also are part of group Z), 
then status A is true.
```

Multiply by several dozen statuses and possibly hundreds of groups and attributes.  The people, groups, and attributes are all in the database.

Though this will be consumed by a Java app, we also want to be able to run reports directly against the database, so it would be best if the set of computed statuses were available at at the data level.

Our current design plan, then, is to have a table or view that consists of a set of boolean flags (hasStatusA? hasStatusB? hasStatusC?) for each person.  This way, if I want to query for everyone who has status C, I don't have to know all of the rules for computing status C; I just check the flag.

(Note that, in real life, the flags will have more meaningful names: isEligibleForReview?, isPastDueForReview?, etc.).

So a) is this a reasonable approach, and b) if so, what's the best way to compute those flags?

Some options we're considering for computing flags:

1. Make the set of flags a view, and calculate the flag values from the underlying data in real time using SQL or PL-SQL (this is an Oracle DB).  This way the values are always accurate, but performance may suffer, and the rules would have to be maintained by a developer.
2. Make the set of flags consist of static data, and use some type of rules engine to keep those flags up-to-date as the underlying data changes.  This way the rules can be maintained more easily, but the flags could potentially be inaccurate at a given point in time.  (If we go with this approach, is there a rules engine that can easily manipulate data within a database in this way?)

Comment: How often will your data be updated?  Are we talking these status could change each minute, hour, day, week?

Comment: Your example reads like Prolog.

Comment: Attributes could change daily; groups maybe monthly.  Statuses should ideally be accurate within a minute or so of an attribute change. The rules themselves should change less often; maybe every few months.

Comment: re prolog: it's true, although my example was meant more to indicate how the rules will have nested if/then logic, etc.  I did read a bit about the concept of "deductive databases", which use rules, typically in prolog, to deduce a set of facts based on data.  That's perfect, but I don't think there are any real-world-ready systems like that, and I doubt my colleagues will want to learn prolog (and I haven't used prolog in 20 years myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a case like this I suggest applying Ward Cunningham's question- ask yourself "What's the simplest thing that could possibly work?".

In this case, the simplest thing might be to come up with a view that looks at the data as it exists and does the calculations and computations to produce all the fields you care about.  Now, load up your database and try it out.  Is it fast enough?  If so, good - you did the simplest possible thing and it worked out fine.  If it's NOT fast enough, good - the first attempt didn't work, but you've got the rules mapped out in the view code.  Now you can go on to try the next iteration of "the simplest thing" - perhaps your write a background task that watches for inserts and updates and then jumps in to recompute the flags.  If that works, fine and dandy.  If not, go to the next iteration...and so on.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against making the statuses as column names but rather use a status id and value. such as a customer status table with columns of ID and Value.

I would have two methods for updating statuses. One a stored procedure that either has all the logic or calls separate stored procs to figure out each status. you could make all this dynamic by having a function for each status evaluation, and the one stored proc could then call each function. The 2nd method would be to have whatever stored proc(s), that updates user info, call a stored proc to go update all the users statuses based upon the current data. These two methods would allow you to have both realtime updates for the data that changed and if you add a new status,  you can call the method to update all statuses with new logic.

Hopefully you have one point of updates to the user data, such as a user update stored proc, and you can put the status update stored proc call in that procedure. This would also save having to schedule a task every n seconds to update statuses.

Answer (score 0):

An option I'd consider would be for each flag to be backed by a deterministic function that returns the up-to-date value given the relevant data.

The function might not perform well enough, however, if you're calling it for many rows at a time (e.g. for reporting). So, if you're on Oracle 11g, you can solve this by adding [virtual columns](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402) (search for "virtual column") to the relevant tables based on the function. The [Result Cache](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00817) feature should improve the performance of the function as well.